# how to set authentication key with hyphen

Tags: zapier

I have to trigger an email when the user logs in.

My login API header requires the following data

```
Content-Type => application/json
tenant-id => 
event-id => 
Device-id => 
Api-Key =>
```

When I am setting key as "Api-Key" it throws an error as below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

I'm not sure which page that's for, but it looks like you're adding a trigger field when you probably want the API key to be in the authentication instead.

Check out the docs here: https://zapier.com/developer/documentation/v2/authentication/

If you do have a header that needs a `-` in it, you can add this in scripting as described [here](https://zapier.com/developer/documentation/v2/code-examples/#trigger-pre-poll-examples)

```
some_header_pre_poll: function(bundle) {
    var request = bundle.request;
    request.headers["X-Project-ID"] = bundle.trigger_fields.project_id || "None";
    return request;
  },
```